# Visual Studio Update Startup Form Changing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have an application that I am working on in Visual Studio 2022 VB.NET. I want to change the startup form from Form1 to frm_Main.

I go to Project >> Project Properties >> Startup Form; but the only form listed in the drop down is Form1 which was created when making the project. I cannot seem to get frm_Main to be an option.

I created frm_Main but going to Project >> Add New Item >> Form (Windows Form); typed in the name and clicked add.

Some light on this would be awesome.[image]

Comment: In Solution Explorer, click the `Show All files` button, then expand `My Project`, open up `Application.myapp` and change the `<MainForm>` value.

Comment: It worked like a dream thank you. I don't know why the other way isn't working but this was perfect

Comment: It's a problem with the VB.Net configuration applet in .Net Framework applications - Note that you could also build a .Net 6 Project, then - in Solution Explorer - right-click the starting Project, select `Edit Project File` and change the Target Framework from `net6.0-windows` to `net48` (`<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>`), rebuild, (=> VB.Net Only) [close VS and restart it].

Comment: I looked for the .Net 6 when I start the VB.Net project and I know I have it downloaded but the best i get is 4.8 so I ran with that

Comment: That's because you keep on selecting the `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` template instead of `Windows Forms App` (which defaults to the most recent **.Net** version installed <- not **.Net Framework**) when you create a new Project.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue, which will be fixed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10039228.